# Overfill oil on 1.5 Liter VTEC-e Civic 1995

Tags: civic, oil-change, valve, fluid-level

I have a 1.5 Liter VTEC-e Civic 1995. The valves are noisy if I fill oil up to the manufacturer recommended level. But if I overfill by a quart the engine and valves are much quieter.

Is this related to the age of the engine? Any thoughts about the cause of this would be appreciated.

Also, would overfilling cause any damage?

Comment: You're probably going to end up sucking oil into the intake. Have you ever done a valve adjustment?

Comment: How much is the manufacturer recommended? Usually 10% of overfill is pretty safe, on some engines 20% overfill will not create any drug on engine crankshaft. So there is no any damage of a little overfill. Just make sure you are measuring the oil level correctly (leveled surface, engine turned off for long time).